# Lucene 4 - get all used fields from directory

Tags: lucene

im trying to index a database table with Lucene 4. I index all fields of a table entry into a document as a TextField (1 document per table entry) and try to search over the directory afterward.

So my problem is, that i need all the field names that are in the directory to use a MultiFieldQuery.

`QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, !FIELDS! , analyzer);`

How do i get them? I could save them away while indexing, but it wouldn't be very performant to log them away with the index :/

Thank You
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the fieldnames from [`AtomicReader.getFieldInfos()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html#getFieldInfos%28%29).

That will pass back a [`FieldInfos`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfos.html) instance.  Loop through `FieldInfos.iterator()`, and get the field names from [`FieldInfo.name`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfo.html#name)

I don't see why it wouldn't be performant to store them somewhere ahead of time, though.

Comment: The static method `wrap` of the class [SlowCompositeReaderWrapper (Lucene 4.2.0 API)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/SlowCompositeReaderWrapper.html) can be used to create an `AtomicReader` instance from an `IndexReader.